# How to list nodes and have them grouped by Day / Week / Month?

Tags: datetime

I have an event content type that has a date field (the time the event will take place)

I like to list these events and have them grouped by Day / Week / Month
I dislike the calendar layout, it is too messy

Any ideas are welcome

I attached this mockup of what i'm looking for. The person interested in the event's section should be able to filter the events by day/week/month

[image: Events filtering by day, week, month]

*Extra question :* Would it be possible to have a 'next weekend' filter (relative to the time the person is visiting the website) ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a custom PHP field and manually code out the group by conditions as you have set there. I had the same issue I documented on my blog here: http://drupul.com/content/views-multiple-group-recipe-drupal-7

This is the code I used in my PHP field:

```
<?php 
global $prev_month;
global $month;

if($prev_month != date('F Y', strtotime($data->field_field_date_2[0]['raw']['value'])))
{ 
  $month = '<h4>'. date('F Y', strtotime($data->field_field_date_2[0]['raw']['value'])) .'</h4>'; 
  $prev_month = date('F Y', strtotime($data->field_field_date_2[0]['raw']['value'])); 
} 
else 
{ $month = ''; }

print($month .'<h5>'. date('M d', strtotime($data->field_field_date_2[0]['raw']['value'])) .'</h5>');
?>
```

You will of course have to modify it to your setup, but its very similar to the setup you need as I needed it to be grouped by month then week and then day.